# Getting the URL of the webpage where the redirect occurred

Tags: jsp, redirect

I have 2 web pages written using JSP :

1. The first page is for login once login is success
2. Welcome page is displayed.

If the user enters the URL of the welcome page from the browser without being logged in ,I have written a code to redirect to the Login page.

Is there any way by which I can get the URL in login page of the welcome page from where this redirect occurred ?

HTTP header "referer" seems to work only if the user clicks on the link.

**EDIT:** One way i can think of is pass the parameter in the url with the value as welcome page while redirecting.Is there any other better way?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What method do you use to redirect to the login page?

Comment: JSTL <c:redirect url="http://localhost:8000/Login/"/> and web.xml has the welcome file as Loginpage.jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what the original page is, use client-side redirection, such as: `<script language="javascript">window.location='http://localhost:8000/Login/';</script>` instead of the way you're doing it now.